# Converting a windows web.config rule to an .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, iis, iis-7, web-config

I have the following rule in a web.config file on a windows machine. It takes any request that contains `http://domain.com/shop/[stuff]` and routes it to `/category.php`. I am moving the site to a PHP server, but I'm not sure how to make this rule an .htaccess rule.

Note that the web.config rule keeps the query string if it is present.

```
    <rule name="Rule for shop pages.">
      <match url="(.*/)?shop/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/category.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
RewriteRule (.*/)?shop/* /category.php []
```

For more help in the future I recommend you to use http://tohtaccess.com/ a website to convert web.config rewriting rules into htaccess format.